# Extract words surrounding a UNICODE word

Tags: python, regex, unicode

This code works perfectly for this English sentence.

But when I try to do this with a sentence in Hindi language, it gives me error that word is not in the list.

This is my Hindi sentence:

```
प्रखर बुद्धि तेजस्वी बालक राजेन्द्र बाल्यावस्था में ही फारसी में शिक्षा ग्रहण करने लगा और उसके पश्चात प्राथमिक शिक्षा के लिए छपरा के जिला स्कूल |
```

I want to extract words adjacent to the word `बालक`.

Python code:

```
import re

sentence = 'The world is a small place, we should try to take care of it.'

words = re.findall(r'\w+', sentence)

index = words.index('place')

left = words[index - 3:index]

right = words[index + 1:index + 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may do like this on python 3.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'प्रखर बुद्धि तेजस्वी बालक राजेन्द्र बाल्यावस्था में ही फारसी में शिक्षा ग्रहण करने लगा और उसके पश्चात प्राथमिक शिक्षा के लिए छपरा के जिला स्कूल |'
>>> re.findall(r'(\S+)\s+बालक\s+(\S+)', s)
[('तेजस्वी', 'राजेन्द्र')]
```

ie,.

```
>>> left, right = re.findall(r'(\S+)\s+बालक\s+(\S+)', s)[0]
>>> left
'तेजस्वी'
>>> right
'राजेन्द्र'
>>>
```

**Update:**

To get two adjacent words.

```
>>> left, right = re.findall(r'(\S+\s+\S+)\s+बालक\s+(\S+\s+\S+)', s)[0]
>>> left
'बुद्धि तेजस्वी'
>>> right
'राजेन्द्र बाल्यावस्था'
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, But I want to extract 2 words from both Right and Left side of the word.

Comment: How do I print 2 consecutive words?

Comment: # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
datafile = file('test.txt')
found = False
for line1 in datafile:
    if 'जादुगर' in line1:
        print line1
datafile1 = file('test.txt')
for line2 in datafile1:
    if 'बालक' in line2:
        print line2
        s = line2
        for line2 in datafile1:
            left, right = re.findall(r'(\S+\s+\S+)\s+बालक\s+(\S+\s+\S+)', s)[0]
            print left
            print right

Comment: Actually i am trying to do this. If you run you will come to know. When we search the word 'Balak' from the file, i want to print the adjacent words to it.